# Iterate over tree and calculate sum of special nodes

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

I have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, bool include, int age)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Include = include;
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Include { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

I create objects in this way:

```
var Persons = new List<Person>();
Persons.Add(new Person("Eric", true, 12));
Persons[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Tom", false, 13));
Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("John", true, 10));
Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Bill", true, 23));
Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Paul", true, 100));
Persons.Add(new Person("John", true, 12);
Persons[1].Childs = new List<Person>();
Persons[1].Childs.Add(new Person("Jay", true, 15));
Persons[1].Childs[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
Persons[1].Childs[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Billy", true, 23));
```

This produces the following tree:

```
-Eric (true, 12)
    -Tom (false, 13)
    -John (true, 10)
        -Bill (true, 23)
    -Paul (true, 100)
-John (true, 12)
    -Jay (false, 15)
        -Billy (true, 23)
```

What I want to do is to create a function that returns the highest sum of ages where Includeis set to `true` based on the following algorithm:

- All nodes must be selected for which Include is set to true.
- From these nodes, retrieve all subnodes and subsubnodes for which Include is also set to true and calculate the sum of ages of every possible coalition. Return the largest one.
- When Include of a subnode is set to `false` ignore all subnodes of the subnode even when they have Include set to true. So calculate all direct ways from top to bottom where Include is set to true and return the largest one.

Example: Calculate First:

- 12 + 10 + 23 = 45 (Eric + John + Bill)
- 12 + 100 = 112 (Eric + Paul)
- 12 (John, because Jay has Include set to false ignore Billy)

Then return highest value of sum: `112`

EDIT:
What I have tried so far

```
public int GetMax(Person p){
    foreach(var pi in p){
        if(pi.Include) {
            // how do I save sums?
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Even though you have posted code, it in no way contributes to how the problem mentioned in the latter half is to be solved.  You are essentially posting a set of _requirements_ this making your question _too broad_.  Sadly SO is not a code writing service.  [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with recursion, however you can also chuck it in the class.

```
internal class Person
{

   ...

   public int MaxStuff => Include ? Age + (Childs?.Max(x => x.MaxStuff) ?? 0) : 0;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var total = persons.Max(x => x.MaxStuff);
```

---

Or recursive

```
public static int MaxStuff(Person p)
    => p.Include ? p.Age + (p.Childs?.Max( MaxStuff) ?? 0) : 0;
```

**Usage**

```
var total = persons.Max(MaxStuff);
```

Comment: I have to do it with recursion, but I do not know how to save the previous sum values.

Comment: @bob This is recursive :) just not a standalone method

Comment: I mean in a function outside the class :)

Comment: I must admit i really learnt something from this exercise, say thank you to your teacher for me